# Is there a way to bypass XSS errors in CxSAST Scan?

Tags: jenkins-groovy, checkmarx

Is there any configuration option available to ignore XSS errors in CxSAST Scan?

Comment: Interesting question. Can you share the use case, why do you want to ignore that error?

Comment: We use jqurey in our project for dom manipulation. Previously, when checkmarx version 8.x.x used there were no xss errors. Now after upgraded to latest checkmarx version 9.3.0.1139 scan reports xss errors in all jquery methods.

Comment: Not sure why it is occurring suddenly with the latest version of checkmarx? But definitely it would take more time to fix all these errors and test the same.

Comment: You know, when you upgrading software, you get more accurate results...

Answer (score 1):

You can turn off XSS queries in the preset selected for your project if you are getting false-positive results.  If it is a web application, it is not advisable to do this.

It isn't clear from your question, but if you are scanning the jquery library you will probably want to exclude it from the scan via the folder/file exclusions.  If the results are showing you sources in the jquery methods, this would indicate you are scanning the jquery library.  Excluding it will also likely improve your scan performance.

The general rule is to scan only the code which you maintain and is deployed to production.  This means you exclude things like third-party code, unit tests, integration tests, etc.

More results on a new version would not be uncommon, especially in a jump from 8.x to 9.3.  There were several improvement efforts on Javascript in the recent past (8.9+) to improve accuracy.  You'll probably want to set up your exclusions then take a very close look at the results to make sure they are not true-positive results.

Comment: I'm already excluding all thirdparty libs from scanning. Also the xss errors are thrown inside my project files on which jquery manipulation methods like append(), html(), text(), etc being used.

Comment: @sana sait You should probably post code and the name of the result you are getting.  Your results may be true-positive DOM XSS issues that are now being detected more accurately due to the improved Javascript support in 9.3.

Comment: `ndOptionGroup = $("<optgroup>").attr(oOption).attr("label", oOption.text);
ndSelect.append(ndOptionGroup);`

Comment: **Scan result:** The application's method name(in my code) embeds untrusted data in the generated output with append at the filename. This untrusted data is embedded straight into the output without proper sanitization or encoding, enabling an attacker to inject malicious code into the output.

Comment: `if(o.bCustom === true || o.bubble === false){
     
 ndMessage.html(o.text);

}
else if(bHTML) {
     
  ndMessageText.html(o.text);

}
else{
     
 ndMessageText.text(o.text);
}`

Comment: Here errors thrown at html() and text() methods. It reports xss errros on data passed to these methods.